# JSONModel: MKAnnotation & CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I am using JSONModel (https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) inorder to handle my JSON data. I just have problem related to adding a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property in my `JSONModel` Subclass, in order to respond to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. Since the incoming JSON dosen't contain a coordinate field, but seperated fields with Lat & Lon, and since `CLLocationCoordinate2D` isn't an object, `JSONModel` want let me ignore  protocol.

This is my code:

```
@protocol Store @end
@interface Store : JSONModel <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSNumber *Longitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSNumber *Latitude;

//Can be ignored since it is not an object type. 
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D <Ignore> coordinate;
@end
```

How can I ignore the coordinate property?

Answer (score 3):

Just check the documentation

[http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSONModel/0.11.0/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/propertyIsIgnored:](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSONModel/0.11.0/Classes/JSONModel.html#//api/name/propertyIsIgnored%3a)

Here's the code for your model:

```
+ (BOOL)propertyIsIgnored:(NSString *)propertyName
{
  if ([propertyName isEqualToString:@"coordinate"]) {
    return YES;
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Edit: Although what I would do if I were you is to have a custom transformer for the coordinate property that would read the 2 incoming json keys and produce a location struct for you automatically. Just an idea...

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried the code, but I get the following warning: Keys missing: {(
    coordinate,
    title,
    subtitle ... Thank you for the idea, would you could give me an example of how this would look like? :D

Comment: It looks to me like there is something else at play here.  The code [here](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel/JSONModel.m#L640) tries to match out via `scanner` the string that represents the struct name and put it into `p.structName`.

However, in my experience with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that string can be an encoding of the sort `@"T{?=dd},N,V` where the question mark does not match the struct name.  Still trying to get the proposed solution by Marin to work since I can't make a custom transformer work correctly.